# Azure Load Test. Understanding how virtual users effect performance

Tags: azure, performance-testing, load-testing

I’m trying to make sense of the results of a recent Azure cloud load test, that we ran against one of our API’s

As I’m testing an API, I’ve configured the load test virtual users to have no think time. So essentially, every time a virtual user receive a response, it sends another request straight away.

We are also not using any kind of user sessions, or caching any data per user. It's a basic test, that posts some JSON to an endpoint on the API, which then performs some calculations of the data it received.

It appears that by changing the amount of virtual users, we can make the service more performant. By which I mean, it can respond faster and still process more requests per second.

The results of two load tests are shown below.

[image: Load Test]
The first test, tells me that our API is capable of processing 60k requests in 2 minutes.

What I can't understand, is why adding more virtual users, increases the average response time and lowers the RPS, which in turn causes the API to only process 55k requests in 2 minutes.

Why would the API now only be able to handle 460 RPS, when we already know it can handle 500 RPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 questions here:
1.why more virtual users increase response time;
2.why more VU decrease RPS;
3.why more VU decrease total requests.

Here are the explanations:

1. More concurrent VUs create more concurrent sessions that require more resources on the server (e.g. session context, size of queues, thread concurrency) that increase server processing time and response time from the client perspective.
2. Decreasing RPS would be inconsistent in this situation only if the load generator issues requests with constant frequency inconsequential of receiving responses. In reality, after issuing a request each VU waits until the response is received. Since the server response got slower, the wait time increased, which causes decrease in RPS.
   There is a 2nd answer to this question. Because the load generator performance capacity is limited, emulating more VUs requires more resources on the client which can cause delays in issuing requests. While you configure your test with zero think time, the load generator can inadvertently inject delays that cause additional RPS decrease.
3. The number of total requests is proportionate to the number of VUs and RPS. Apparently in your case RPS reduction had a bigger impact, and the number of total requests diminished.

Generally, effect of decreasing RPS caused by increasing VU in load testing looks like a paradox, when in reality it is not.

Comment: I had some performance counters inside the service itself, so I could see that the service was taking longer to respond when there was more users.

So I dont think the load generator was inadvertently injecting delays in my tests. As you suggested, it may be something related to more current sessions. I'll keep digging. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no "exact" single reason, but remember that, as you increase the number of load generators, you're also increasing number of connections, number of parallel operations on the server, etc. You cannot assume that, by increasing user load over time, you'll continue to get better throughput and response times. In fact, sometimes you will increase load and find the elusive "knee in the curve" on your performance graph - where latency spikes (along with request failures), while throughput plummets. And from a load-testing perspective, this would be a Good Thing, since you'd now have a fairly good idea of what to expect from your existing software+infrastructure in terms of transaction rates etc.

You'll need to dig into things further to determine exact reason, but it could easily be related to thread pool exhaustion, memory issue, cpu issue, disk issue, bottleneck on a specific resource (e.g. cache or database), network saturation, etc.

Comment: "you'd now have a fairly good idea of what to expect from your existing software+infrastructure in terms of transaction rates etc" That's the thing, right now I don't. 

I was load testing because I wanted to make sure the API could cope with 500 RPS. Technically the first test handled 500 RPS, with no problems and responds quickly. 

I have no idea, what the live environment will be closer to though. The 200 virtual users or the 300 virtual users.